# Mandos: smart contract invalid when deploying a smart contract

Tags: multiversx, erdpy

I created a smart contract and I want to test it using the mandos framework. When I run the `erdpy contract test`, it fails with the following command output:

> Output: Scenario: contract-deploy.scen.json ...   FAIL: result code mismatch. Tx 1. Want: 0. Have: 9 (contract invalid). Message: invalid contract code

How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get invalid contract code, you can update your arwen version by:

```
erdpy config set dependencies.arwentools.tag v1.4.21
erdpy deps install arwentools --overwrite
```

And finally, if compilation fails with some weird messages, make sure to update your Rust installation:

```
erdpy deps install rust --overwrite
```

Comment: 1: CRITICAL:cli:Configuration entry is not known: dependencies.arwentools.tag.
------ 2: error: argument name: invalid choice: 'arwentools'

Comment: try `erdpy config set dependencies.vmtools.tag` instead

Comment: @matei's answer worked for me, as well.